# If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue for $A$, then $k\lambda$ is eigenvalue for $kA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We know that

> if a matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, then the matrix $kA$ has eigenvalues $k\lambda_1,\dots,k\lambda_n$.

An example is the matrix

$$A=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 & -2\\ -2 & -2 & 1\end{matrix} \right)$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-3$, $\lambda_2=3$, compared to the matrix
$$\frac13 A=\frac13\left( \begin{matrix}1 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 & -2\\ -2 & -2 & 1\end{matrix} \right)$$
that has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$, $\lambda_2=1$.

I am not able to justify the statement based on the process of finding eigenvalues, since determinant is not linear, and so we have, for the characteristic polynomial
$$|kA-\lambda I|=k^n|A-\frac{\lambda}{k} I|$$
and don't know how to proceed from here.

I should clarify that I'm looking for a proof that

> if $\lambda_0$ is a root of $|A-\lambda I|$, then $k\lambda_0$ is a root of $|kA-\lambda I|$

Comment: Use the definition of eigenvector to say If $A\vec v=\lambda \vec v$, then $kA\vec v=k\lambda \vec v$

Comment: Added what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't see why this question was downvoted

Comment: The MSE community is weird sometimes

Comment: Isn't $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ implies $\det(kA - k\lambda I)=k^n\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ the reasoning you are looking for?

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon should be $\det(kA-\lambda I)$, different from $\det(kA-k\lambda I)$, because the first one is the characteristic polynomial for the matrix $kA$,  the one you wrote is not. So not the reasoning I'm looking for

Comment: In my comment, $\lambda$ is a fixed value which is a solution to the characteristic polynomial of $A$. The characteristic polynomial of $kA$ is the function of a variable, say $x$, given by $x \mapsto \det(kA - x I)$. A solution to this polynomial is the fixed value $x=k \lambda$.

Comment: I see now. So my question was trivial, what a disappointment

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon Avoid answering questions in comments. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: More general result is true. If $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A,$ then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(A).$ The simplest proof can be given as in the first comment of @J.W.Tanner . Another explanation: $p(\lambda)I-p(A)=(\lambda I-A) q(A),$ where $q(x)=[p(x)-p(\lambda)]/(x-\lambda).$ Then the determinant of $p(\lambda )I-p(A)$ vanishes if $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A.$ This follows from the product rule for determinants.

Comment: didn't know this result, very cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be a solution to the characteristic polynomial of $A$ i.e. $\lambda$ is a fixed value satisfying $\det(A- \lambda I) = 0$. The characteristic polynomial of $kA$ is the polynomial function of a variable, say $x$, sending $x \mapsto \det(kA-x I)$. This function evaluates to zero when it takes as argument the fixed value $k\lambda$ in place of $x$.